# How to automatically archive AWS S3 whole buckets to S3 Glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm required to archive around 200 AWS S3 buckets to S3 Glacier and I would like to do it automatically but I can't find how it can be done with aws-cli.

The only method I found, is through AWS UI... to go to each bucket manually and within it, to mark each directory -> right click and choose "change storage type" and choose Glacier.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://bucketname s3://bucketname --recursive --storage-class GLACIER
```

Be aware that [there is a cost](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) to transition objects to the Glacier storage class (approximately US$0.05 per 1,000 transition requests, dependent on region, so changing 1,000,000 objects to Glacier would cost approximately US$50).

Answer (score 3):

You could also set up lifecycle policies on the buckets so that they automatically transition to Glacier after x amount of days:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

I think `aws` cli with `s3 ls`, `s3 mv` and `--storage-class` should do the job.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

It should be possible to use the same source and destination with `mv`.